# Finding all possible kernels

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the following problem below and how to approach it.

$$
    A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Find all $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ker(A-xI) \neq \{0\}$. Where $I$ is the identity matrix.

$\ker\begin{pmatrix}
    1 - x & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5-x & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9-x \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

Looking at this question above, it looks like I must somehow find the eigenvalues of matrix A and use it somehow to find all possible kernels that do not equal the 0 vector. Taking the kernel of a matrix without variables is relatively straightforward and I would end up with a span of some vectors. Any insight on this question will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At this stage of your studies you should have learned that for a square matrix $M$, $\ker M\ne\{0\}$ iff $\det M=0$. So you just need to solve $$\det\pmatrix{1-x&2&3\\4&5-x&6\\7&8&9-x}=0$$ for $x$, which is indeed one of the standard methods of finding the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition was correct: prove that $x\in\Bbb R$ is an eigenvalue for the original matrix iff that kernel is nontrivial. So you just need to find the eigenvalues.

> Both state that $(A-xI)v=0$ for some nonzero $v\in \Bbb R^3$.

Comment: The required set is R-{a,b,c} where a,b,c are the eigen values of A. The eigen values are in fact 0, 15 plus or minus sqrt(297) whole divided by 2. Here R is the real Field.

Comment: @LawrenceMano The required set is those $x$'s where $\ker(A-xI)\ne\{0\}$, i.e. the 3 eigenvalues.